# dhcp client cannot ping google.com

Tags: linux, centos

I have 2 nic server. eth0 and eth1
eth0 conected internet and its connected Static 
IP address 192.168.1.200
DNS 192.168.1.1
GW 192.168.1.1

eth1 configured as dhcp server and assign ip address to clients.
ip address 192.168.27.1
DNS 192.168.27.1
GW 192.168.27.1
RANGE 192.168.27.2, 192.168.27.200

DHCP client ping with eth0 and modem
but the problem is i cannot access internet
dhcp client cannot ping google.com

Comment: @jimmij /etc/resolv.conf                                                                                        option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.1, 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4

Comment: @ jimmij option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.1, 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4
option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.1
; generated by /sbin/dhclient-script
search domain.name dhcp
nameserver 192.168.1.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8

Answer (score 2):

You've specified a default gateway 192.168.27.1 for `eth1`. This means you're saying any system on the IPv4 internet should be reachable by sending packets through 192.168.27.1.

The system is probably believing you and trying to connect to the internet through 192.168.27.1 because its gateway entry happens to be before the 192.168.1.1 gateway entry in the routing table.

If `eth1` is not connected to the internet, don't specify a default gateway for it. Leave the GW entry for eth1 blank.

From the question comments:

> /etc/resolv.conf option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.1, 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4

`option domain-name-servers ...` is the configuration syntax for `dhcpd.conf`; it is not correct for `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: Thank you for ur information. But dhcp client can ping 192.168.1.1. It is the eth0 GATEWAY

Comment: Yes, because it is clear to the server that any traffic to 192.168.1.* must go out of `eth0`. But the problem is in routing any traffic whose destination is neither 192.168.1.* nor 192.168.27.*. What does `ip route show` or `/sbin/route -n` say on the server?